# Java user interface, one listener, 12 object to display both image and description

Tags: java, user-interface, object, jframe, jlabel

first post for me here at stackoverflow, been following for a while tho!
i am stuck with this and its due tonight.

I am not sure how to go about cycling through the fish objects with the action listener... how would i get the imageicon and descption label to change to the next fish, depending on the season!

It says no arrays
im really stumped here guys...

the actionlistener only had those if statements because i was experimenting ways to get this working.

grateful for any help or suggestions!

-------(Problem 2 Outline)-------

You decided to take your family on a vacation getaway to do some deep sea fishing. You have already planned your getaway in the sun.  You struck a deal with one of the fishing companies to help them display the fish they are currently catching. You are to create a simple graphical program that will display all your photos and a caption that goes with it.

You need to create a simple GUI application that creates 3 different fish photos object depending on the time of year.
You should allow the user to enter (through a text box) the time of year.  The user should be able to enter Fall, Winter, Spring or Summer. 
You should have a Fish class that you create and instantiate.
You should display the picture and the caption/description of the fish. 
You should have two buttons to go forward and backward between the photos.
Each time the forward button is pressed, a new photo should appear including the picture and caption.
Each time the back button is pressed, the previous picture and caption should appear.
You cannot use arrays.
You must a single button listener for both buttons.

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel myTitleLabel = new JLabel ();

    JButton nextButton = new JButton();
    JButton backButton = new JButton();
    JLabel buttonLabel = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon ("", "Image Will Display Here");
    JLabel myPictureLabel = new JLabel (image);
    JLabel fishDescription = new JLabel ();
    JTextField seasonText = new JTextField();

//imageicons that hold the images of each fish  
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish1.jpg");
    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish2.jpg");
    ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish3.jpg");
    ImageIcon image4 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish4.jpg");
    ImageIcon image5 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish5.jpg");
    ImageIcon image6 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish6.jpg");
    ImageIcon image7 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish7.jpg");
    ImageIcon image8 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish8.jpg");
    ImageIcon image9 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish9.jpg");
    ImageIcon image10 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish10.jpg");
    ImageIcon image11 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish11.jpg");
    ImageIcon image12 = new ImageIcon("src/Images/fish12.jpg");


    //10 fish objects with an image, description, and a season
    Fish fish1 = new Fish (image1, "this is a trout ", "fall");
    Fish fish2 = new Fish (image2, "This is a big mouth bass ", "fall");
    Fish fish3 = new Fish (image3, "this is a pompato", "fall");
    Fish fish4 = new Fish (image4, "This is a freshwater drum fish", "winter");
    Fish fish5 = new Fish (image5, "this is a yellow perch ", "winter");
    Fish fish6 = new Fish (image6, "This is a Iowa Darter ", "winter");
    Fish fish7 = new Fish (image7, "this is a bull trout ", "spring");
    Fish fish8 = new Fish (image8, "This is a chinook salmon", "spring");
    Fish fish9 = new Fish (image9, "this is a Channel Catfish ", "spring");
    Fish fish10 = new Fish (image10, "This is a Yellow Bullhead", "summer");
    Fish fish11 = new Fish (image11, "this is a Northern Pike", "summer");
    Fish fish12 = new Fish (image12, "This is a Tiger Muskellunge", "summer");


public MainPanel ()
{

    Font font = new Font ("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,800));

    myTitleLabel.setText("<html>Fishing by Seasons<br> "
            + "Enter a season to see the fish caught then</html>");

    myTitleLabel.setFont(font);


    nextButton = new JButton ("-----------NEXT!-----------");
    backButton = new JButton ("-----------BACK!------------");

    seasonText.setFont(font);

    seasonText.setText("  ---  Enter a Season  ---  ");

    nextButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
    backButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    myPictureLabel.setIcon(image);

    add(myTitleLabel);
    add(nextButton);
    add(backButton);
    add(myPictureLabel);
    add(fishDescription);
    add(seasonText);
}




public void fishSelector()
{
    int count = 0;
    count++;
}



private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        //this is probably incorrect.. was trying stuff out...
        if (event.getSource()== "-----------NEXT!-----------")
            myPictureLabel.setText("going to next");
            fishDescription.setText(fish1.toString());


        if (event.getSource() == "-----------BACK!------------")
            myPictureLabel.setText ("going back");



    }

}

}



public class Fish {



private ImageIcon myImage;
private String imageDescription;
private String fishSeason = "winter, summer, fall, spring";



public Fish(ImageIcon myImage, String imageDescription, String fishSeason) 
{

    this.myImage = myImage;
    this.imageDescription = imageDescription;
    this.fishSeason = fishSeason;


}


public String toString ()
{
    return imageDescription;
}
}
```

Comment: No array? Use a LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest - the handling in the action listener is incorrect :
the event.getSource() returns a component (JButton) and not the text . so you have 2 options :

1. check which button pressed ( better )
2. check by the name of the button pressed

in both ways you first need to find the button that was pressed by :

```
    private class buttonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // this is probably incorrect.. was trying stuff out...
        // if (event.getSource() == "-----------NEXT!-----------")
        // checking the button is better than checking it's text
        //
        if ((JButton)event.getSource() == nextButton)
            myPictureLabel.setText("going to next");
        fishDescription.setText(fish1.toString());

        if ((JButton)event.getSource() == backButton)
            myPictureLabel.setText("going back");

    }
```